# What is the fastest way to copy large postgres(>1TB) database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Original Problem Statement:
Create a test DB with the latest production database(RDS Postgres)greater than 1.5 TB quickly.

We have 1 production database running in a single instance and we have 8 dev/test databases running in another instance.  The snapshot copy will create a new instance and DB but I am looking to copy only the DB from production and restore it to multiple DB's on another instance. I need to refresh dev/test DB's frequently with production data.

Solution:

1. pg_dump the production database and restore it to a new test database. This takes more than 6 hours.
2. Identify the delta from the tables and export only the data or tables that have changes.
   There are a lot of tables and I am in process of identifying the tables with changes. But again do not know how much time this takes.
3. A crazy thought and not a solution - Create a read replica outside RDS and use forking to copy the changes.  The main idea of forking is from this https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-for-postgresql-96-on-ubuntu-1604/
   I am not sure if this is even possible as AWS RDS masks a lot of their configurations.

How do I achieve a copy faster.?

I am not sure if StackOverflow is the right place to ask this question.

Comment: You probably cannot get very fast, because you are limited by the internet and Amazon's I/O speed. If you have requirements like that, don't use hosted databases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion@LaurenzAlbe.  What is the usual option DB users use for fast copy.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @Rohit: if the target server can connect to the source, `pg_basebackup`  is as fast as it gets

Comment: Production databases have backups. Restore backups to test dev/test to refresh them with production data. This also lets you verify the backups as working.

Comment: "We have 1 production database running in a single instance and we have 8 dev/test databases running in another instance"  Why?  If you want 8 test databases, why not just have 8 test instances.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name and Brian.  I will try these options.

Comment: @jjanes It's due to the cost involved in running 8 instances. Forgot to mention they are all in AWS RDS. We used to run them separately but later moved to this model due to cost. I work in a startup and at the moment we are trying to keep our cost low.